# Can Electron's spellCheckHandler be used to arbitrarily flag substrings in a textarea?

Tags: electron, spell-checking

I'm having trouble finding any documentation of this, official or unofficial. There are several modules on github that implement traditional browser-style spellchecking but they're not providing much insight.

Is there an API here that will let me do the red underline squiggle any time it sees the substring "abc" in a given textarea?

Answer (score 2):

The method [webFrame.setSpellCheckProvider](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-frame#webframesetspellcheckproviderlanguage-autocorrectword-provider) can be used to set a custom spell-check function.

For instance, this simple code snippet will implement a spell-checker function which will mark with a *red underline squiggle* each typed word which is either `abc` or `xyz` in input fields and text areas:

```
const { webFrame } = require ('electron');
//
const badWords = [ "abc", "xyz" ];
//
function customSpellCheck (word)
{
    return !badWords.includes (word);
}
//
webFrame.setSpellCheckProvider ('en-US', true, { spellCheck: customSpellCheck });
```

Alternatively, you can use the following spell-checker function if what you want is to mark words *containing* a substring among `abc` or `xyz`:

```
function customSpellCheck (word)
{
    return !badWords.some (badWord => word.includes (badWord));
}
```

Please note that the `webFrame.setSpellCheckProvider` interface is going to be different starting from Electron 5.x.x, as it will make use of a deeper callback function...